# Random characters in CSS class names

Tags: html, css, dom, sass

I have noticed one thing. On some sites such as tray.io, asana, fb etc They have random characters in css class names when you inspect them for example:

```
<header class="Header_XSDsdksdXKkSDD">..</Header>
```

Why are these characters generated and how are they generated?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those class names or identifiers are probably generated by the engine that produces the page output.

If you want to add a style to a particular element, you want a unique class for it - the easiest way is to generate some pseudo-random identifier.

Comment: Webpack has an option to obfuscate class names, see https://develoger.com/how-to-obfuscate-css-class-names-with-react-and-webpack-20e2b5c49cda

Answer (score 3):

These are probably hash string of a technology similar to [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules).

The main idea is that you use a tool that reads the CSS files and makes unique classes for your different "views". Doing this separates the CSS files per HTML file / template / JSX or whatever your setup is.

If you follow the idea behind it, you can easily achieve more scalable setup of your code, because it allows you to use `global` and `local` class names. This means that you will not rely on the "cascading" feature of the CSS to propagate any styles.

Comment: What's the purpose of doing that? How does it allow for global and local class names when CSS, as far as I am aware, has one scope?

Comment: It works when your HTML is actually written in JS. Check out this article https://x-team.com/blog/css-modules-a-new-way-to-css/