# Classes are random strings -- webpack thing or CSS framework?

Tags: css, webpack

When I inspect Facebook and other enterprise sites, most elements have a long set of random string classes like `class="rq0escxv l9j0dhe7 du4w35lb j83agx80 pfnyh3mw taijpn5t gs1a9yip owycx6da btwxx1t3 dp1hu0rb"`.

Is this a webpack thing or a CSS framework?

Comment: I think they obfuscate their classes so it's harder to reverse engineer how facebook works. And this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38942184/random-characters-in-css-class-names. I'd say it's React doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably they use css-in-js approach (https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html#can-i-use-inline-styles).
They define all their CSS rules for a particular element as plain object, pass the object to a lib, the lib parses the object and hashes it to create a class name.

Then apparently they extract those rules into a separate css files.